# How to detect a change of content for Android Webview. For example, money.cnn.com works strange

Tags: android, android-webview

Usually, when you click inside **Android WebView** page and transfer to another page, `WebViewClient` receives call to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method. But, this doesn't work with **money.cnn.com**. When I browse on **money.cnn.com**, I receive callbacks only into `onPageStarted` and into `onPageFinished`. Both only once. Browsing inside the site after doesn't give any callbacks to `WebViewClient`. If I browse only inside the **money.cnn.com** my log shows only these two lines. No more, no less.

```
> 10-14 14:10:25.581 28886-28886/com.myapp I/MyApp: onPageStarted
> 10-14 14:10:36.822 28886-28886/com.myapp I/MyApp: onPageFinished
```

My code is:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(mSWWebViewClient);                        
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl(getUrl());
WebViewClient mSWWebViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
       super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
       Log.d("MyApp", "onPageStarted ");
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       super.onPageFinished(view, url);
       Log.d("MyApp", "onPageFinished ");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       Log.d("MyApp", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading ");
    }
};
```

My question is why `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` doesn't receive callback at all, and how can I detect a change of the content of this site while browsing through it?

**Edition**
Finally, I have finished with the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551880/955321

Comment: Use `public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651586/difference-between-shouldoverrideurlloading-and-shouldinterceptrequest

Comment: No, it is not what I mean. I need to intercept the main url of the page, not the every url for every content

Comment: I'm not clear based on your last comment what you are looking for. My only suggestions are to use `shouldInterceptRequest` to monitor XmlHttpRequests. And use Chrome debugging tools https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ to see how the page is written and to see how content is loaded.

Comment: I thought you recommend me to use shouldInterceptRequest instead of shouldOverrideUrlLoading. Actually, the site use html 5 and dom storage. It made me add mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true). The site showed infinite loading without that line of code. The problem is: I need to show different views over the main webview, depending on what type of content appears: the main page or an article. But, I don't receive any callbacks when I surf from the main page deeper inside. Morrison, maybe you've faced already a situation like that?